# Winforms Datagrid, display foreign key

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Currently I have a DataGrid, and a datasource.

The Datasource is directly pulled from the database in this order:

Id, SalaryId, Old, New

Problem is that it displays the SalaryId, I want it to display the SalaryId Value

How do I do this?

Comment: Can you clarify the distinction between "the SalaryId" (which it shows now) and "the SalaryId Value" (which you want to show).

Comment: @Marc : 

Salary has the following rows:

Id, Value.

I want to display this:

Id, Salary.Value (referring through the SalaryId), Old, New

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pure guess here, but you probably just need to rewrite your original SQL query from something like:

```
SELECT ID, SALARYID, OLD, NEW FROM tblEMPLOYEE
```

to something like:

```
SELECT a.ID, b.SALARYVALUE, a.OLD, a.NEW FROM tblEMPLOYEE a, tblSALARY b
WHERE a.SALARYID = b.ID
```

Comment: well that's what I want to avoid, I don't want to do a join.

Comment: Well, your alternatives are: 1) run your original query, then iterate through the rows in your result set, running a separate query against the Salary table to replace SalaryID with Value; or 2) magic. Why don't you want to do a join?